# Javascript function is no longer working or affected all colors

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/37kf31uz/

So for some reason after I put in the numSquares in the generateRandomNumbers function the page won't on initial start have random colors. all my colors are purple. I previously have generateRandomColors(6); instead. but I'm following a guide and i've been trying to figure out why mine isn't working properly and showing different colors on start up.

```
var colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = pickColor();
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");
var messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
var resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
var easyBtn = document.querySelector("#easyBtn");
var hardBtn = document.querySelector("#hardBtn");
var numSquares = 6;

easyBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    hardBtn.classList.remove("selected");
    easyBtn.classList.add("selected");
    numSquares = 3;
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        if (colors[i]) {
            squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        } else {
            squares[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
});
hardBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    hardBtn.classList.add("selected");
    easyBtn.classList.remove("selected");
    numSquares = 6;
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
        squares[i].style.display = "block";
    }
});


resetButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);
    pickedColor = pickColor();
    colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
    this.textContent = "New Colors";
    messageDisplay.textContent = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    }
    h1.style.backgroundColor = "steelblue";
});

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    //add initial colors to squares
    squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

    //add click listeners to squares
    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        //grab color of clicked squares
        var clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
        //compare color to pickedColor
        if (clickedColor === pickedColor) {
            messageDisplay.textContent = "Correct."
            resetButton.textContent = "Play Again?";
            changeColors(clickedColor);
            h1.style.background = clickedColor;
        } else {
            this.style.background = "#232323";
            messageDisplay.textContent = "Try Again."
        }
    });
}

function changeColors(color) {
    for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
        squares[i].style.background = color;
    }
}

function pickColor() {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[random];
}

function generateRandomColors(num) {
    //make an array
    var arr = []
    //add num random colors to array
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        //get random color and push into array
        arr.push(randomColor())
    }
    //return that array
    return arr;
}

function randomColor() {
    //pick a "red" form 0-255
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    //pick a "green" form 0-255
    var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    //pick a "blue" form 0-255
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)
    "rgb(r, g, b)"
    return "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
}
```

Comment: Please include the html part also or any jsfiddle to check it.

Comment: ok, i put a jsfiddle in there. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move the line `var numSquares = 6;` to the top of the code, because `var colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares);` is dependent on the numSquares variable.

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/robwelan/pen/QMwWRM).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case of [Javascript hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

In brevity, the JS engine sees the code as

```
var colors;
var squares;
var pickedColro;
var colorDisplay;
var numSquares;
var h1;
var easyBtn;
var hardBtn;
colors = generateRandomColors(numSquares); //numSquares in undefined here
squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
pickedColor = pickColor();
colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");
messageDisplay = document.querySelector("#message");
h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
resetButton = document.querySelector("#reset");
easyBtn = document.querySelector("#easyBtn");
hardBtn = document.querySelector("#hardBtn");
numSquares = 6;
```

So you are in actuality passing undefined to the generateRandomColors.
**Move the `var numSquare=6` to the top** , and you should be seeing the multicolored tiles that you wish for.

Comment: Wow, that is so odd and thank you so much. it was killing me the for the past 2 hoursxD